Why would my setTimeout() return a random number on screen when the callback function executed
I am trying to learn Svelte by building a quiz app.
What I wanted to achieve is that when the user has answered a question from the quiz, it automatically jumps to the next one. I set a setTimeout() of 1 second so the user has a bit of time to see if he has answered correctly or not before being directed to the next question.
This works but I find that every time the toNextQuestion() funtion runs, it would print a random number value on screen, like being added to DOM.
I google and it seems that a setTimeout() funtion would return a number value as its ID. but can I bypass it here?
What should I do to achieve the goal while not having a random number added to DOM?
My code is like:
<script>
    const toNextQuestion = () => {
        currentQ uestionIndex += 1;
        correct = undefined;
        questionAnswered = false; 
    };
</script>

  {#await promise}
    <p>...waiting</p>
  {:then data}
    <h1>Question {currentQuestion} of {data.results.length}</h1>
    <em>Score: {score}</em>
    {#each data.results as questionData, index}
        {#if index === currentQuestionIndex}
            <Question
                {questionData}
                {questionAnswered}
                {answerQuestion}
                {evaluateAnswer}
            />
        {/if}
    {/each}

    {#if questionAnswered}
        {setTimeout(() => {toNextQuestion()}, 1000)}
        <!-- Here it would add a random number TODO -->

    {/if}

    {#if currentQuestionIndex == data.results.length - 1}
         <!-- Here for completing the quiz TODO -->
    {/if}
{/await}

Any advice would be appreciated ! Thank you so much!

The setTimeout() function returns a number. The number is an identifier for the timer itself, for use with clearTimeout(). Your code explicitly puts the return value from the setTimeout() call in the content.

Wrap it in an IIFE i.e. (() => {})()
{#if questionAnswered}
    {(() => {
        const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
            toNextQuestion();
        }, 1000);
        // Do not return anything...
    })()}
{/if}

This way you have a void function call, but why are you trying to render this in the DOM in the first place?

Thank you so much! Indeed, I was blinded by myself... I don't need to render it in the DOM at all! I moved the code to a function in javaScript now and things works perfectly. Thanks!

setTimeout returns a handle for use with clearTimeout.
You generally should not have code with side effects in the template, there are no guarantees on when and how often that code may be called.

Thank you! I see. So I should avoid setTimeout()? What is code with side effect?

Anything that mutates state is a side effect. setTimeout has side effects as it registers a global timeout in the window. I.e. you should only read state in the template (event handlers are different, they do not get executed during template rendering but usually upon some interaction).
